# Set custom legend shape manually

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a boxplot.

```
ggplot(iris,aes(x=Species,y=Petal.Width,col=Species))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

I would like to change the default shape in this legend above (line boxplot-like) to a simple line rectangle or point shape like below.

[image]

I only want the legend shape to change and rest of the plot should stay as it is. Here is an example where the legend has been manually edited in a photo editing tool.

[image]

I have tried a few variations like below, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
ggplot(iris,aes(x=Species,y=Petal.Width,col=Species))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  guides(color=(guide_legend(override.aes=list(linetype=0,shape=16))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get a little hacky and add `geom_point(alpha = 0)` to the plot:

```
ggplot(iris,aes(x=Species,y=Petal.Width,col=Species))+
    geom_point(alpha = 0)+ # totally transparent
    geom_boxplot(show.legend = FALSE)+ # don't show boxplot legend
    guides(color=(guide_legend(override.aes=list(alpha = 1))))
```

[image]

And you can play with `shape` to have the rectangle:

```
ggplot(iris,aes(x=Species,y=Petal.Width,col=Species))+
    geom_point(alpha = 0)+
    geom_boxplot(show.legend = FALSE)+
    guides(color=(guide_legend(override.aes=list(alpha = 1, shape = 22, size = 6,
                                                 fill = 'white'))))
```

[image]